# Should I report suspected illegal activity from a product I've developed (and to whom)?

Tags: software-industry, project-management

I helped develop a product that had the intent of making it a lot easier for people to do task X at lower cost Y. However, since the soft launch of the product, I've observed substantial log data indicating that the primary user class of our product may be users performing illegal activity Z.

This not the actual scenario, but imagine some magical accounting software that helps you diversify your funds at low fees, but upon launching the software, you observe a pattern of users creating an account, completing a large diversification, then never using their account again. The employees developing the product often joke that the product may be used for that activity, but no one seems to care about stopping the activity.

What should I do?

Comment: If you want to not end up in jail, you should probably talk to a lawyer rather than asking random people on the internet what to do (you may very well be considered an accomplice at this stage). If your only worry is ethics or morality, you're welcome to follow your own judgement regarding the way forward.

Comment: I suspect a lot is going to depend on whether it can be shown that the software was intentionally developed in order to carry out illegal activity Z, or whether that was completely unforeseen by the developers (or at least there's no evidence that it was foreseen).  But as others have said, only a lawyer can give you real guidance here.

Comment: Can it be patched to make activity Z impossible or at least highly inefficient?

Comment: Financial software is often highly regulated and policed. How the client uses it isn't your problem though. BUT if you host it or are involved in any way, you're in the firing line and may have obligations to report and/or keep records for set periods. So be careful. Best to write your software with full knowledge of and based on the regulations and write in blocks to anything potentially illegal, or write and make plain that potentially illegal activities are logged and traceable. My own financial software got many people fired and sent several to jail because it logged their activities.

Comment: I think I'm just going to quit.

Answer (score 1):

If you suspect it is indeed illegal activity then by all means consider reporting it.

However, don't bring it up assuming that it is truly such illegal activity, instead try mentioning it as something you have seen and found unusual, something like *"Hey guys, I noted that the logs of the software seem to suggest people may actually be doing activity Z. What do you think, should we do something about it?"*

This I suggest you bring up to those employees developing the product you mentioned, the project Lead, or to the corresponding manager in charge. If you think this is urgent, then calling them or going to their office would be more effective than writing this on an email.

Be ready to back up what you say with the data you can safely disclose or share from the logs, and also try thinking of alternatives or ways to stop or prevent this from happening, so you can propose those in case it is necessary to take action.

Answer (score 1):

With software, the biggest problem is that you can't control the way someone uses it.Considering that your app is being used the wrong way try to implement a way that user won't be able to do that.

> The employees developing the product often joke that the product may be used for that activity, but no one seems to care about stopping the activity.

This statement states that you require taking the issue to some higher authority so that the developers take it seriously.

And for considering preventing misuse of your app consider the example of StackExchange itself.How the users are not allowed any malicious activities considering millions of users.

Comment: "And for considering preventing misuse of your app consider the example of StackExchange itself.How the users are not allowed any malicious activities considering millions of users." - Well, it is not like people can evade taxes or shadily steal/save money on funds on Stack Exchange. At most people farm reps (which are imaginary points though). I agree with the rest of your answer.

Comment: @DarkCygnus: they can learn to exploit a security whole, write software to hide or facilitate their illegal activity.

Comment: @jmoreno yes, but that is something you can't do or learn directly on SE, thus my comment and why I though that to not be a good example for this case. You can hardly do illegal things by exploiting things on SE, but exploiting a financial software *can surely* have illegal applications.

Comment: My example was to ask op to have a more secure app like SE  has.We don't find people spreading anything that goes against SE rules just like that I wanted to suggest OP to make app more secure @DarkCygnus

Comment: I see, still don't think is too comparable both of them. It is not like SE is subject to the risks that a financial app may have. But yes, OP should look into other secure apps or projects to think of ways to prevent this. Besides from that, you answer is good :)

Answer (score 1):

The answer to this question varies widely based on the reality of what Z is and is it illegal for the result of doing Z or is it illegal to perform the action that causes Z.

If it is illegal to do the action that causes z, then your product is the one technically breaking the law and you are technically facilitating the process of breaking the law.  That makes you personally potentially criminally liable.  Thus you would need a lawyer.

If your product is just one that can be used to commit a crime Z but the actual action the software takes is not illegal, then you are just creating a tool.  A knife can be used to stab someone, it can also be used to prepare food.  The creation of the knife is not the problem it is the people who use the knife to stab people.

Now if your product makes it possible to commit the crime Z in a way that was never before possible that could also expose you to liability. For instance your Knife creates wounds that can not be healed in a normal fashion.   In that case you also should consult a lawyer and use that information in determining how to go forward.

Answer (score -2):

If there is any remote suspicion of illegal use of any company owned tool, application or whatever else while you are aware of it and not reporting it, you are actually being an accomplice to the crime. Considering, you have developed this tool, when this illegal activity blows up, I am sure someone will come to you and start asking questions like "were you checking the logs ?" When you (expectedly) say yes, the next question will be "How haven't you noticed this activity and if you did, how come you did not report it ?"

I think you've got the gist of where I am going with this. If I were you, I would stop procrastinating and report it to HR, ethics compliance or if it is really bad, to the law enforcement professionals. If there is a crime being committed, you really do not want to find yourself at the wrong side of the law, when the doo-doo hots the fan.

Comment: *you are actually being an accomplice to the crime* - Citation Needed